# How can I tether my Sony a5000 to my MacBook Pro?

Tags: sony, tethering, macintosh, apple

I am looking to be able to watch myself film on my MacBook pro through the sony a5000 and was wondering if this was possible and how? Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at either Sony's Camera Remote Control or (if you don't mind paying) Capture One Pro (for Sony)?

Comment: You should follow up and let everyone know if any of this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Every Mac ships with an application called Image Capture. It's in your Applications folder. It tethers to a lot of cameras. Give it a try. Free and it works great.

Comment: I tried Image Capture on macos 10.14.6 with a5000 firmware 1.10 and it did not work.  I tried all three USB configuration options on the camera.  Image Capture _would_ try to import images in two of the USB modes, but no tethering.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but the A5000 *can* be used as a "webcam" using the [OpenMemories-Tweak](https://github.com/ma1co/OpenMemories-Tweak) from `ma1co` on GitHub.

I've successfully used [this procedure](https://github.com/ma1co/OpenMemories-Tweak/issues/70#issuecomment-731626365) (modified slightly since I used the macos version of `pmca-gui`) to output *clean* (ie: no on-screen displays) 1080p from the micro HDMI port.  I use a $15 USB 3.0 HDMI video capture device and have used it with Google Meet, the macos Photo Booth app, and OBS.

I've noticed the cheap capture card has a slight lag, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Tethering your camera is supported by both Sony Camera Remote Control and Capture One Pro but Live View is not.

DigiCamControl http://digicamcontrol.com/ claims to support Live View with your model.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Live view is available for free through [darktable on macOS](https://www.darktable.org/). The refresh rate is low and the picture quality is poor but it is a live view nonetheless! For those struggling, sometimes other processes hijack the connection to the camera so I tried killing processes in Activity Monitor and successfully got a connection to darktable.

Live view is provided through gphoto2, [which has a list of supported cameras](http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php).

-

At the time of writing this, Sony has updated their software to [Imaging Edge](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/app/imagingedge/en/download/). This supports the A5000 (ICLE-5000) but does not provide a live-view option.

Testing with my A5100 it works over USB and does have a nice set of options.

[Imaging Edge interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G15Hf.png)

Using the mobile app Sony PlayMemories on my iPhone, I can get live view for the A5100, but the refresh rate is at around 1 Hz.